# What would you like to do about menu.lst?

Tags: server, 18.04, upgrade, kernel

Every time I update my Ubuntu 18.04 server I have a dialog box that opens and says

> A new version of /boot/grub.menu.lst is available, but the version
> installed currently has been locally modified.
>
> [image]

What should I answer, and why ?

Comment: Do you understand the question?

Comment: Is your server a computer which you run, or is this hosted https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+A+new+version+of+%2Fboot%2Fgrub.menu.lst+is+available%2C+but+the+version+installed+currently+has+been+locally+modified   somewhere else for you? Please reply by clicking [edit] here and explain how you use that server; please do not click on Add Comment, but instead use [edit] .